# Yii2 How create ActiveDataProvider with union from different models

Tags: sql-server, gridview, yii2, union, dataprovider

I'm trying to create union from two different models the two models have same column `id, body` below the error when send `dataProvider` to `GridView`:

`SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ((SELECT [id], [body] FROM [web_article] WHERE body LIKE '%a%') UNION ( SELECT [id], [body] FROM [email_article] WHERE body LIKE '%a%' )) [c]`

I copied the `sql` query then run it on `MSSQL Server` and it return result!

Below the controller code:

```
$model = new DynamicModel([
    'text', 'type'
]);

$model->addRule(['text'], 'required')
      ->addRule('text', 'string');

$emailArticle = EmailArticle::find()->select('id, body')->where('body LIKE :query')->addParams([':query'=>"%{$model->text}%"]);
$webArticle = WebArticle::find()->select('id, body')->where('body LIKE :query')->addParams([':query'=>"%{$model->text}%"]);
$webArticle->union($emailArticle);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $webArticle,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 21,
    ],          
]);

return $this->render('form', [
    'model'=>$model,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Comment: not sure if **ActiveRecord** got a **union** method try to [merge](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#merge()-detail) results instead, if not try with **QueryBuilder**. you may also need **mdmunir** solution in [this open issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7992#issuecomment-89890274)

Comment: You can use SqlDataProvider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `SqlDataProvider` instead of `ActiveDataProvider` below the final code:

```
$sql = "(SELECT [id], [body] FROM [web_article] WHERE body LIKE '%{$model->text}%' UNION SELECT [id], [body] FROM [email_article] WHERE body LIKE '%{$model->text}%')";
$totalCount = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $sql AS [c]")->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => $sql . ' ORDER BY body',
    'totalCount' => (int)$totalCount,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],          
]);
```